Create Bin using ASP.Net Core
View
@model BinViewModel

<form id="binForm">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.StreetName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.StreetName, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Street Name", @autocomplete = "off" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.StreetName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.Capacity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-form-label" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.Capacity, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Capacity", @autocomplete = "off" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.Capacity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit" id="btnCreateBin" class="btn btn-success">
            <span class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw"></span> Create Bin
        </button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

Model
 public class CreateBin
 {
     public string? StreetName { get; set; }
     public string? Capacity { get; set; }
 }
 public class BinViewModel
 {
     public CreateBin CreateBinModel { get; set; }
     public List<Bin> Bins { get; set; }
 }

Bin.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#binForm').on('submit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).serialize());
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Bin/Create', // Your action URL
            type: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    $('#createBinModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#successModal .modal-body p').text(response.message);
                    $('#successModal').modal('show');
                } else {
                    // Display error modal with the error message
                    $('#createBinModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#errorModal .modal-body p').text(response.message);
                    $('#errorModal').modal('show');
                }
            }
        });
    });
});

Image:


I trying to Add bin then the value of model is null, Then i checked in the console log there are something. In the attached image I currently encountered issue. Can't pass properly the value of the form to the model.
Can anyone help what is the mistake in the code.
Thank you

The request payload sent doesn't match the structure that your Create API expects to receive the payload with the CreateBinModel instance as the properties sent with the "CreateBinModel" prefix.
You can provide the Name attribute to overwrite the original generated name attribute.
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.StreetName,
    new { Name = "StreetName", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Street Name", @autocomplete = "off" })

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreateBinModel.Capacity,
    new { Name = "Capacity", @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Capacity", @autocomplete = "off" })




Thank you for your answer @Yong Shun. I tried your suggestion but still same issue I encountered.

Hmmm, I share the screenshots in the answer. It seems can't reproduce your issue on my local side. Check whether your $(this).serialize() value (especially for the StreetName and Capacity fields) is updated according to my first screenshot.
